# Large Matrix to run in cv.glmnet() for multinomial classification

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, logistic-regression, glmnet, multinomial

I am working on a large matrix with number of samples N=40 and features, P=7130. I am trying to fit the `cv.glmnet()` for the ridge but i am getting error while doing this.
The dimensions of the dataset is (40,7130)
The code for the cv.glmnet() is as follows:

```
ridge2_cv <- cv.glmnet(x, y,
                   ## type.measure: loss to use for cross-validation.
                   type.measure = "deviance",
                   ## K = 10 is the default.
                   nfold = 10,
                   ## Multinomial regression
                   family = "multinomial",
                   ## ‘alpha = 1’ is the lasso penalty, and ‘alpha = 0’ the ridge penalty.
                   alpha = 0)
```

Here `x` is large matrix with 285160 elements. `y` is the multi-class response variable of size 40
I keep getting this error when i run the above function.

`Error in cbind2(1, newx) %*% (nbeta[[i]]) : 
  invalid class 'NA' to dup_mMatrix_as_dgeMatrix
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In lognet(x, is.sparse, ix, jx, y, weights, offset, alpha, nobs,  :
  one multinomial or binomial class has fewer than 8  observations; dangerous ground
2: In lognet(x, is.sparse, ix, jx, y, weights, offset, alpha, nobs,  :
  one multinomial or binomial class has fewer than 8  observations; dangerous ground`

Comment: can you edit your question to show us `str(x)` and `str(y)`  (and maybe `table(y)`) ?

Comment: @BenBolker I figured out the problem when i checked the `typeof(x)` and `typeof(y)`. The dataframe was read as character and i had to use `read.table` and change according to my problem. This solved the problem. Thanks for your suggestion. It gave me idea to solve

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with data.matrix() for the matrix instead of as.matrix? I remember trying out something similar.

```
ridge2_cv <- cv.glmnet(data.matrix(x), y,
               ## type.measure: loss to use for cross-validation.
               type.measure = "deviance",
               ## K = 10 is the default.
               nfold = 10,
               ## Multinomial regression
               family = "multinomial",
               ## ‘alpha = 1’ is the lasso penalty, and ‘alpha = 0’ the ridge penalty.
               alpha = 0)
```

Comment: Yes your answer is right in some cases, but my issue was with compatibility. The data was being read as character when i transposed the matrix. I changed it to read as double and it worked. Thanks for your suggestion